# Java superclass calling a method created in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question about Inheritance and Binding.

What if I create a new method in a subclass, and try to call it with the superclass reference?

I know that it will check first the type, and after that the object. 
So according to the rules this is not going work, because this method is not declared in superclass.

But is there no way to overcome it?

I mean does Inheritance mean, that you must declare every single method in superclass, and if you would like to change something for subclass, you can only override it?
So if suddenly I realise, that one of my subclasses does needs a special method, or needs an overloading, then I eather forced to declare it in superclass first or forget about it at all?

Comment: Even if this were possible, it should never be done. A super class should have no knowledge requirement for its children.

Comment: Re `"But is there no way to overcome it?"` -- there's nothing to overcome since this should never be done. Consider posting the underlying motivation for this question as your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you called the method in an instance of the superclass which *wasn't* actually an instance of the subclass declaring the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if suddenly I realise, that one of my subclasses does needs a
>   special method, or needs an overloading, then I eather forced to
>   declare it in superclass first or forget about it at all?

There is a third option. Declare the method in the subclass. In code that needs to call the method, cast the reference to the subclass type. If the reference does not really point to an object of that subclass, you will get a ClassCastException.

If you end up having to do this sort of thing you should take another look at it during your next refactoring pass to see if it can be smoothed out.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Test().toString());
    Test sub = new TestSub();
    System.out.println(sub.toString());
    ((TestSub)sub).specialMethod();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "I'm a Test";
  }
}

class TestSub extends Test {
  void specialMethod() {
    System.out.println("I'm a TestSub");
  }
}
```

Comment: `"...to see if it can be smoothed out."` -- how would you smooth it out? Visitor Design Pattern? Or is this too broad of a question? Thanks as always.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't know a one-size-fits-all solution. During refactoring, I would review the general area to see if there is smooth way of avoiding the cast.

Answer (score 0):

create an abstract method in the super class (and change the super to an abstract class) then call the abstract method in the super class.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon DwB's answer: create a default no-op method.

```
public class Super {
    public void special() {
        // no-op
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    @Override public void special() {
        System.out.println("Now I do something");
    }
}
```